# Administration rails 3.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

What kind of plugins should i use to handle administration in rails 3.2.2 app?
My scenario is user should login  using Ldap authentication.There should be roles like 
(admin guest user) where i can add user and then attach actions (delete update create) 
through user interface. Will be LDAP Authentication With Devise and declarative
administraion the right choice? or is better to look at something else?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like [ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info/) or [RailsAdmin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) would a great solution. I know that RailsAdmin will use Devise and CanCan. Hope this helps.